# What is the most bulletproof and elegant way, to copy an array to another in different scenarios?

Tags: c, arrays

After I found this very helpful Q/A: [How to initialize all members of an array to the same value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/201101/1370465), I came to wonder, if there is an equivalent for my constant problem of how to exchange data between arrays in `C`.

These are some of the cases which interests me the most:

1. same type to same type, with same size (e.g char to char)
2. one type to another, with same size (e.g. const char to unit8)
3. smaller one into a bigger one (e.g test[7] to test[70])

My methods for those above would be like this - e.g.:

1. `array1 = array2`
2. `memcpy(&array2,array1,sizeof(array1))`
3. eighter `memcpy` too, or a for loop through the elements

I hope someone here can provide, or knows where to find, a fine distilled example-collection of different array exchange routines. It's not, that I cannot make it work my self, it's just, that there is this constant insecurity, if the solution is solid.

Oh, and I really hate those for-loops, assign each element individually. For me, the only reason to use them is when there is some additional handling necessary before the exhange is performed - e.g. incrementing the transferred value first, or something like that.

In case this does not sit well with Q/A-Style, I would be happy, if someone could confirm or improve my attempt for example no.2:

```
#define SIZEOF_ARRAY = 16;

uint8 array2[SIZEOF_ARRAY+1];
const char array1[SIZEOF_ARRAY+1] = {"test"};

memcpy(&array2,array1,sizeof(array1))
```

Comment: Would it be possible to use setup array2 to array1 values though pointers instead of memcpy? My guess was not, because array1 is const. Is that right?

Answer (score 4):

First, your case 1 doesn't make sense, you can't copy to a `const` array. It's constant.

Then, two nitpicks with your code for the 2nd case:

1. Array names decay to pointers to the first element in cases like that, so the `&` is not needed.
2. `sizeof` is not a function, so the parenthesis are not needed.

Thus:

```
memcpy(array2, array1, sizeof array2);
```

Note that it's a bit dangerous to do this, you must be sure that the sizes really match.

Comment: thanks for the hint with `const`, corrected it. Your reduced form is quite nice, and in my case, I am sure about the size, BUT shouldn't such code always be secured against bad usage? Would you yourself use another way to achieve the same result?